# How to make a progress bar/meter in web2py?

Tags: python, html, progress-bar, web2py

I made a progress meter in web2py, but it only shows up in the terminal window. How can I make the progress bar/meter to work in the web2py's HTML page?

Here's a part of the code:

```
k = 1 # This is the loop variable for subplots.
for counter in nus:
    fig = plt.figure()
    D = E*(h**3)/(12*(1-counter**2)) # Cylindrical rigidity.
    T0 = (L**2)/(D*np.pi**2)*T0_orig # Nondimensional tension.
    amax = T0/kappa # Maximum allowed alpha (to keep tension nonnegative everywhere).
    alphas = [0, (10**-6)*amax, (10**-4)*amax, (10**-2)*amax] # Nondimensional alphas to use for plot.
    workdone = 0.0 # How much of the Figure has been calculated? 0.0 = none, 1.0 = Figure is ready to show.
    workstep = 100.0/len(alphas) # How much work is done during one step in the loop? If there are 4 steps in the loop, then then step will be 100.0/4 = 25.0.
    for alpha in alphas:
        lambda_, xx, f = nonhomog_solver(kappa, alpha, nu, nx)
        V0 = np.sqrt( T0_orig/m + np.pi**2 * D/(m*L**2)*lambda_ )
        if (k == 1):
            V0_ref = V0

        # Figure 1
        fig_a = fig.add_subplot(2,2,k)
        fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4)
        if (k == 1):
            fig_a.set_title(r'$\alpha / \alpha_{max} = %.2g, V_{0}^{ref} = %.6g$ m/s' % (alpha/amax, V0))
        else:
            fig_a.set_title(r'$\alpha / \alpha_{max} = %.2g, V_{0}/V_{0}^{ref} = %.6g$' % (alpha/amax, V0/V0_ref))
        fig_a.plot(xx,f)
        plt.xlim(-kappa,kappa)
        plt.xlabel(r'$\eta$')
        plt.ylim(-0.1,1.1)
        if ((k == 1) or (k == 3)):
            plt.ylabel(r'$f(\eta)$')
        workdone = workdone + workstep
        print "Figure 1:", workdone, "%/100.0% done."

        # Let's get ready for the next subfigure.
        k = k + 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be better off asking the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/web2py).

Is your code inside (or called by) a controller function? Note, print statements don't send any output to web pages (i.e., they don't affect the HTTP response) -- to do that, your controller needs to return a dict to a view (or return a string). For a progress bar, you may end up needing to use [Ajax](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/10) (also, see [here](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/13#Components)).

This [Client Tools](http://www.web2pyslices.com/main/slices/take_slice/8) module has a progress bar example (scroll to the "Even more examples" section). I haven't used it and am not sure it fits your use case, but it may give you some ideas.